# How can I used MinGW gdb to debug my program that was compiled using msvc?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gdb

I want to use MinGW gdb to debug my application that was compile using msvc. Is this possible? If yes. How?

Comment: What happens if you *try* it?

Comment: when I run gdb with the application, gdb said .. (no debugging symbols found)